# How can I log shutdown console text?

Tags: shutdown, log

In Oneiric shutdown is a lot slower than in previous releases and when I look at the console text while shutting down there seems to be a problem with the network manager. Now I wanted to know how I log the text being shown during shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shutdown (and boot) messages are logged in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: as of Ubunutu 16.04 this seems no longer correct. i.e. I don't get `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i "stopped target user"` (and similar. also sanity-tested the contrary), despite that this was part of the previous shutdown... (visible, when pressing ESC to kill the splash screen while shutting down)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't record the shutdown message log anywhere and there's no way to force it to, at least not on my install of Oneiric, not the messages you see scrolling by during shutdown as you frantically reach for your cellphone camera to snap a pic of the dreaded "[fail]" message before it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

I also expect Ubuntu 11.10 to be slower because of network-manager. While shutting down it seems to time out and end with the message

"nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down. ..."

I have removed the network-manager and configured my ip address by using /etc/network/interfaces and it is now fast again.

Comment: I replaced Network-Manager with Wicd, downloaded some nicer icons from gnome-look and my computer shuts down in an appropriate time. But I wanted to file a bug on Launchpad with the shutdown text to get Network-Manger back as it's nice than Wicd.