# Where in Ubuntu 16.04 is the shutdown log?

Tags: shutdown, services, log, logging

Yes, I am aware of 
[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58625/where-is-the-shutdown-log)
[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68563/how-can-i-log-shutdown-console-text)
[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68563/how-can-i-log-shutdown-console-text)
and
[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259219/how-to-read-shutdown-reboot-log?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer.

Still, I can't find the log information (the log lines I see when pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> during splash screen. For example *‘stopped Target User and Group Name Lookups.’* ...) in ***any*** of the possible suspects in `var/logs`.

I.e. by looking at the most recently changed files:
(my shutdown was at 11:20h, thus only these files can possibly matter)

```
/var/log $ ll -tr | tail
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root      root  27K 2016-10-27 11:03  Xorg.0.log.old
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 root      utmp    0 2016-10-27 11:20  wtmp
    -rw-r----- 1 syslog    adm     0 2016-10-27 11:20  kern.log
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    0 2016-10-27 11:20  boot.log
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    0 2016-10-27 11:20  gpu-manager
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    0 2016-10-27 11:21  gpu-manager.log
    -rw-r----- 1 root      adm     0 2016-10-27 11:21  apport.log
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root      root    0 2016-10-27 11:21  Xorg.0.log
    -rw-r----- 1 syslog    adm  3,0K 2016-10-27 11:21  auth.log
    -rw-r----- 1 syslog    adm   194 2016-10-27 11:21  syslog
```

Did things change? Do I have to enable (persistent) shutdown logging somewhere?

My shutdown did not fail, took 15-20 seconds and completed. (Multiple runs before I asked this question, naturally). If you wonder about the 0-bytes: Truncated (emptied) those log files before shutdown for simplicity.

Comment: Have you seen http://askubuntu.com/a/774309/158442?